# Python 2.7 Return Value and Adding Functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

Here is a code to print and calculate the weighted exam grade:

```
def exam(weight,score_earned,score_shift): 
    if  (score_shift==1):
        shift_amount=input("What was the shift amount?")
        score_earned=int(shift_amount+score_earned)
    if (score_earned >100):
        score_earned=100
    print("Total points = "+str(score_earned)+str("/100"))
    weighted_score=int((score_earned/100.0)*weight)
    print("Your weighted score = "+str(weighted_score)+"/"+str(weight))
    return weighted_score
def exam_1():
    print("Midterm 1:")
    exam(input("Weight 0-100?"),input("Score earned?"),input("Were scores shifted (1= yes 2=no)? "))
```

I then added another similar function with a different name so...

```
def exam_2():
    print("\nMidterm 2:")
    exam(input("Weight 0-100? "),input("Score earned? "),input("Were scores shifted (1= yes 2=no)? "))
```

After, I added these two together and this is where my issue occurs..

```
overall_percentage =int(exam_1() +exam_2())
```

I wanted the code to add the weighted scores together using the returned weighted_score for each. Although, when I run the code it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How do I fix this?

Here is also an example output--everything works except for the overall_percentage which makes me think something is going wrong with my return statement:

```
Midterm 1:
Weight 0-100? 50
Score earned? 88
Were scores shifted (1= yes 2=no)? 2
Total points = 88/100
Your weighted score = 44/50

Midterm 2:
Weight 0-100? 50
Score earned? 88
Were scores shifted (1= yes 2=no)? 2
Total points = 88/100
Your weighted score = 44/50
```

Comment: Exam_1() and exam_2()  don’t return any values. A function needs to return a value to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your functions `exam_1` and `exam_2` don't return anything ( = `None` ).

That's why `exam_1() + exam_2()` results in `None + None` and throws the exception you're seeing:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

You can fix that easily:

```
def exam_1():
    print("Midterm 1:")
    return exam( ...
```

and

```
def exam_2():
    print("\nMidterm 2:")
    return exam( ...
```